# print all topic in the print version

Tags: python, gensim

Using this command it is possible to present 10 topics.

```
ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=32, id2word=id2word)
pprint(ldamallet.show_topics(formatted=False))
```

How is it possible to print all topics and more than 10 words per topic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print the LDA topics models from gensim? Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016025/how-to-print-the-lda-topics-models-from-gensim-python)

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as accepted (grey tick mark on the left of the answer) and upvoting it if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is enough to check in the [documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html#gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel.print_topic) that `show_topics` takes also an argument `num_words`. Setting it up to 42 will give you 42 words per topic:

```
pprint(ldamallet.show_topics(num_words=42, formatted=False))
```